# Cant move objects in object mode

Tags: objects

I have no clue what i have done that i cant move the object now i was just editing stuff in edit mode, i only added a mirror modifier, but that's it. and now i cant move it on object mode - nor connect it to the body -.

I tried most questions and turning on and off most setting that i tought it would block the movement, but i have no clue how to fix this.

i have no clue what more to put here so i can post the question, ill add a blender file with the head obj so anyone can check what it is and hopefully help me find how to enable movement again.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5548" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5548/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in the 3D View *Properties* panel (<kbd>N</kbd>), all the Transforms are locked

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was that exactly.

Answer (score 7):

It's also possible that you have *Increment Snapping* on
(the little magnet icon in the menu bar of the *3D Viewport*) which could make it appear that it wasn't able to move under some circumstances.

[image: snapping]

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! I was working on a very small scale (a couple cm) so i couldnt tell it was trying to snap to a meter.

Comment: This just helped me. One of those, "I have no idea how it got turned on" things.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who stumbles on this but doesn't find above answers helpful:

1. Go into object mode. Hit <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the side menu.
2. Click on *Tool* to access the tool side menu.
3. Under *Options > Transform* uncheck all 3 check boxes.

Comment: Thanks for adding this. Don't know what shortcut I pressed, but for me under _Options > Transform_, _Affect Only_ was set to Origin. And whenever I was trying to transform the object, only the origin of the object was transformed and the actual object stayed unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a hotkey that you might've bumped, or a script you're using, but basically all of the transformations are locked:

[image]

click all those lock icons and you'll be back in business.

Comment: Thanks , that helped, is there any way that i can lock all the transforms accidentaly? i have no clue how that happened.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently. Press the <kbd>.</kbd> period key and untick *Only Locations*, that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to break transform. if your scene scale is too big and you extend the view clipping distance out too far. I had it set to Clip End 1000000m

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My problem was I forgot I checked a few of the transform Affect Only options. [image]